# Anyway to view original query on top of views using postgres

Tags: postgresql, view, explain

For example, I have a simple query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public';
```

Which turn out very complex, `information_schema.columns` is a complex view.
Right now, to understand the query, I need to read all the definitions of all the views involved.

Is there any way to "expand" query and make it easier to read side by side with query plan output?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to *look under the hood* of the `information_schema` views?

Comment: An application (Hasura) running similar queries just fine on Postgres. After moving to Yugabyte, those queries run painfully slow, I'm trying to add some plan hints but that query make newbie like me impossible to understand...

Comment: Interesting. I'm not a PostgreSQL expert but I would guess your performance issues are highly unlikely related to needing to alter the `information_schema` which should always be performant in itself. I wouldn't doubt you have some other, more global performance issues going on with a different root cause. Have you tested if other queries that don't involve the `information_schema` changed in performance between migrating from Hasura to Yugabyte?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the query, which will show what is really executed on the base tables. That allows you to understand where the slowness is and what causes it. This works for catalog tables just as well as for other tables.